# Parse string as datetime.timedelta argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Consider this method :

```
def duration(duration_type, t):
    t = timedelta(duration_type=t)
```

where `duration_type` is a string representing one of `timedelta` arguments (`days`,`hours`,`seconds`,etc.)

Is there a way to correctly parse the string and feed it as an argument ? Similar to `setattr()` when working with attributes.

Obviously, the code above generates the following error:

`TypeError: 'duration_type' is an invalid keyword argument for __new__()`

---

Use case : Read this value from default python config file and use it in a `timedelta` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use special `**` (double asterisk) to pass dict as named arguments in a function:

```py
def duration(duration_type, t):
    kwargs = {duration_type: t}
    return timedelta(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer, it worked well. But, just a note for you in the future, try avoiding terms like "Easy peasy" and also a quick explanation of your code is generally appreciated by the community.

Comment: One last thing, it might just be me, but the use of `kwargs` here seems confusing since we are not using `**` in the context of  allowing an arbitrary number of arguments, but instead to unpack the values in the dictionnary.